# Log files are being overwritten on tomcat shutdown

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-mvc

I am facing a weird issue. When I shutdown the tomcat first time on a day it is overwriting log file contents. However on 2nd or any subsequent restart  I don't face that issue.

I am seeing following errors in log on tomcat shutdown;

```
23:08:03,390 [] [] INFO XmlWebApplicationContext:873 - Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Apr 29 23:47:05 BST 2015]; root of context hierarchy 
23:08:03,397 [] [] INFO ThreadPoolTaskExecutor:203 - Shutting down ExecutorService 'org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor#1d7b51e8' 
23:11:33,880 [] [] [] INFO PropertiesFactoryBean:172 - Loading properties file from class path resource [apppname/application.properties] 
23:11:41,413 [] [] [] INFO Reflections:238 - Reflections took 5894 ms to scan 112 urls, producing 5518 keys and 32092 values 
23:11:42,242 [] [] [] INFO ThreadPoolTaskExecutor:165 - Initializing ExecutorService 'org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor#28a50da4' 
23:11:42,596 [] [] [] INFO ContextLoader:325 - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 11465 ms 
23:11:48,525 [] [] [] INFO PropertiesFactoryBean:172 - Loading properties file from class path resource [apppname/application.properties] 
23:11:55,130 [] [] [] INFO Reflections:238 - Reflections took 5765 ms to scan 112 urls, producing 5518 keys and 32092 values 
23:11:55,807 [] [] [] INFO ThreadPoolTaskExecutor:165 - Initializing ExecutorService 'org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor#1a46a171' 
23:11:56,081 [] [] [] INFO ContextLoader:325 - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 9491 ms 
23:12:01,469 [] [] [] INFO PropertiesFactoryBean:172 - Loading properties file from class path resource [apppname/application.properties] 
23:12:08,106 [] [] [] INFO Reflections:238 - Reflections took 5757 ms to scan 112 urls, producing 5518 keys and 32092 values 
23:12:08,793 [] [] [] INFO ThreadPoolTaskExecutor:165 - Initializing ExecutorService 'org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor#7213bc54' 
23:12:09,062 [] [] [] INFO ContextLoader:325 - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 9260 ms
```

Log configuration

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/logs/logfilename.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

What can be the possible reason?

I have the same log4j configuration for other application. But they work perfectly fine. It looks like somehow tomcat is writing logs to the the application log instead of catalina.

**It happens only on first restart in a day and when log level is set to INFO or DEBUG not ERROR**.

Answer (score 3):

Use the log4j Append variable. By default it should be true though...

```
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.Append=true
```

I also see you are using Rolling Appender but its not in your root logger

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, RollingAppender
```

Comment: did it fix your issue?

Comment: well! I am not able to reproduce this issue in my local environment. So'll try in other environment. I believe it must resolve the issue. Only the problem is this issue comes only with 1st start in a day. So if I reproduce it tomorrow, I'll nee to wait 1 more day to test if it is fixed.

Comment: Issue looks weird and until the cause is identified, it doesn't seem to be fixed. till now tomcat was backing up current day file then creating new file and start writing new logs. Now with this property tomcat is first backing up current day file then writing to backed up file and new log file both. It happens when backed up file was not present at the time of tomcat stop. So I am trying what happens when back up file presents. I'll update...

Comment: I am using "file" as appender name which is mentioned in root logger. Is there anything wrong with that. Sorry But I cant figure out.